# Want to separate the "onclick" handler from my html markup

Tags: javascript, html

I coded a basic arithmatic calculaor using HTML, CSS AND JavaScript. I have added "onclick" event handler on each button of calculator separately and the function that is performed is same for all "onclick" attribultes. It's working fine. But I want to separate "onclick" from HTML and write the code in JavaScript file which will automatically provide it to all the buttons rather than writing onclick everytime on each button.
I tried to use addEventListener but everytime some kind of issue occured. Below is the code. I want to have the proper event listener code that can solve my issue. Thanks.
[image]
And this is the function which is triggered everytime:

```
function insert(num) {
document.getElementById("textview").value += num;
```

}

Comlete code is in the following GitHub repo:
https://github.com/Badar121/JavaScript-Calculator

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: You can write code in separate js fine and include in script tag . You can get information about event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Add this below where the buttons. This is how you add onClick listeners through a script

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]").forEach(function() {
  this.addActionListener("click", function() {
    insert(this.value);
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a particular identifier to all action buttons, like a CSS class, and then register click event in your js file.

You can refer this snippet.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".action-button");
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", buttonListener));
});

function buttonListener(event) {
    //your logic
}
```